# What is the meaning of "gold person or a silver person"?

Tags: dialogue, phantom-thread

In the movie *Phantom Thread* (2017),  Reynolds, a tailor, meets Mona and asks
her few questions:

> Reynolds: Is Your Royal Highness a gold person or a silver person?
>
> Mona: Silver.
>
> Reynolds: Good. Lace or pearl?
>
> Mona: Lace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is asking Mona about the preferred material.

> Is Your Royal Highness a gold person or a silver person

Roughly translated, this asks Mona about the preference of the "Her Royal Highness", whether she prefers Gold or Silver. Then he keeps going on asking further with

> Lace or pearl?

Finally Reynolds gets the preferred material as Silver colored lace

Answer (score 2):

## It just means "do you have a preference".

It just a common expression like...

Are you cat person or a dog person?

Are you a tea drinker or coffee?

Milk or cream?

Etc.